# Respond.js not working cross domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, media-queries, respond.js

I'm having difficulty getting [Respond's CDN/X-Domain Setup](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#cdnx-domain-setup) working.

I started off serving all assets from the CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.example.com/css/main.css?2013012401">
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?2013012401"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/respond.min.js?2013012401"></script>
```

In theory this should work, since all assets are being served from the same domain. However IE8 didn't receive Media Query support like it should. So I investigated Respond's CDN/X-Domain Setup and amended my `<head>` section to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.example.com/css/main.css?2013012401">
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?2013012401"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/respond.min.js?2013012401"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.example.com/respond-proxy.html?2013012401" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
<link href="http://cdn.example.com/img/respond.proxy.gif?2013012401" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect">
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/respond.proxy.js?2013012401"></script>
```

When that also failed, I amended my `<head>` section to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.example.com/css/main.css?2013012401">
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?2013012401"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/js/respond.min.js?2013012401"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.example.com/respond-proxy.html?2013012401" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
<link href="/img/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect">
<script src="/js/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what else I can try really to get this to work. It works fine in a local Dev environment that's not using the CDN, but in the Live environment this Respond.js CDN/X-Domain Setup is not working. Could it possibly be related to the cache-buster query string added to the CDN assets? Why is my original example not working when all assets are being served from the same domain?

**Edit:** [Here's the error that's thrown in IE8](http://cl.ly/MVQ6/o)

Comment: Having the same issue :-/

Did the CDN/X-Domain Setup, but now it throws a JavaScript error: respond variable not found on line if( respond.mediaQueriesSupported ){ } in IE7.

I have my CSS with media queries on CDN.

Anyone?

Comment: What's your exact implementation? See the answer to my issue given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was caused by the `respond-proxy.html` file reference containing a query string (`respond-proxy.html?2013012401`). Removing the query string from this file causes the above implementation to work.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this fixed it for me too.

Comment: Removing the query string from any of the above code examples should work, but the last one is what I'm using.