# IE8 external stylesheet and relative paths

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Long story short I have an application running in a production environment that contains all of my stylesheets. I am now faced with using these stylesheets on another separate server. This all works fine without any issues in every browser except ie8 (ie9 even works). The external stylesheet appears to be working until it calls a resource using a relative path.

For example the following does not appear in ie8:

```
#header-region #menu .navbar-nav > li > a {
    background: #5f9bbc url("../img/diag_pat_trans.png") repeat;
}
```

The only reason I can think that this would be happening is if every other browser is looking at the stylesheet and when it runs into a relative path it is using the fqdn from which the script was obtained and traversing from its root by whatever realtive path, then when we get to ie8 it is simply obtaining the script code and throwing it in the browser, then when it hits any realtive paths it freaks/ignores!?!?

Curious if anyone else has ran into this issue? Yes the ideal thing would be not to support IE8, but I'm in a position where that is not possible. Any further insight into this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you do know that ie8 does not support border radius right? if your problem is the image url you can always make a conditional comment for ie8 and tweak the url specifically for it. it is not clear when you talk about remote location

Comment: Removed border-radius from example as it's not relevant to the issue. Also re-worded a bit to try and make more clear.

Comment: you should narrow down the problem to either the css or the image. if you use fiddler you can check what full url the image is taking or if the css is even loading, as you may be running into security problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right path with the issue having something to do with cross-domain interaction and IE8. Upon further digging I ran across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564079/respond-js-not-working-cross-domain) where the user was using a respond-proxy.html page to load respond.js, which resolved this issue.